# Book where people are marked with numbers?

Tags: story-identification

About five years ago I read about a society where everyone was marked with a number from 1 to 10, to represent their future position in society. It was completely decided by the people who would tattoo their number. The main character gets a 0, and is chased by the government who wants  to kill him, because a 0 is in reality, better than a 10. It also involved monsters, and was set in sort of a Renaissance era place.

Comment: This is tagged as fantasy-genre, which it shouldn't be, as that implies you are discussing the genre itself. However, if you ment to imply the story you are looking for is a fantasy story, then what about your story makes it so? At a glance it appears to be a sci-fi story.

Comment: Is this a short story or a novel? Do you remember reading it from an anthology, maybe a magazine? Any idea when you read it?

Comment: Not it of course but kind of cute and loosely related, thematically... Significance of numbers, if any, may be revealed if this children's pilot gets picked up. (http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B016J3YR5U/ref=amb_link_445354082_6?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-5&pf_rd_r=0WD2XP6AE0DWEB58FD16&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=2275822962&pf_rd_i=9940930011(

Comment: Possibly answered in  [Book with a world run by dragons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177392/book-with-a-world-run-by-dragons)

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243740/numbers-on-hands-mean-death-if-its-zero-magical-friend-with-a-lucky-hat (which is newer but has an accepted answer)