# Book with a world run by dragons

Tags: story-identification

So basically the boy gets marked as a zero meaning he can’t hold magic and is forced on the run.   It starts with what’s basically a day when kids come of age, they get marked by their magic level, and that determines their social  rank.

Comment: @user14111 - It doesn’t look like any kind of translation to me, rather simply inconsistent autocorrect. Some of the words were mistyped and not corrected (e.g. “thare”) whereas others were corrected. E.g., “East’s” is probably “what’s,” and “kinds” is “kids,
 so “what’s basically a day when kids come of age.”

Comment: Anyway, it’s this: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15815409-dragon-run

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dragon book about a boy who gets marked as a zero on the magic level](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/176820/dragon-book-about-a-boy-who-gets-marked-as-a-zero-on-the-magic-level)

Comment: We shouldn't close this one.  It IS an exact duplicate of another question, but that one doesn't have an answer and is already closed itself.

Comment: The other one has no answers so really the duplicate should go the other way, I’m voting to leave open.

Comment: They're the same question by the same poster.

Comment: Toni, **please don't re-post the same question more than once**. If your original question gets closed, you can always [edit] to improve it and it can quickly be reopened. Posting a new question just adds clutter and can be seen as a form of spamming. (No harm done in this case, though - I'll just delete the older closed incarnation of this question, since it didn't get any answers, and leave this one since it did get answered.)

Comment: Ok thank you and sorry I thought I was editing my last one I didn’t mean to repost it

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243740/numbers-on-hands-mean-death-if-its-zero-magical-friend-with-a-lucky-hat (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 5):

### *[Dragon Run](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0545450683)*

The [Goodreads description](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15815409-dragon-run) says it all:

> A boy goes on the run in this fast-paced fantasy debut.
>
> Can a **zero** become a hero?
>
> **Testing Day** is supposed to be a day of celebration for Al Pilgrommor.
>   Born into a wealthy family, he expects to follow in his successful
>   father’s footsteps. **Of course, that all depends on the rank number Al
>   receives at the testing. The higher the rank he has tattooed onto his
>   neck, the better his life will be.**
>
> To his surprise and horror, Al is revealed to be **rank zero, the lowest
>   of the low.** He’s now not only an outcast — he’s also a danger to his
>   entire family. So Al goes on the run, fleeing the brutal Cullers, men
>   who hunt down zeroes . . . and put them to death.
>
> Cast out of his home, cut off from his friends, and armed with only a
>   sword and his wits, Al is reduced to just surviving. As he meets other
>   outcasts, however, he begins to suspect that he is a pawn in a larger
>   game — and that he might have the power to tip the scales in a
>   **high-stakes struggle between man and dragon.**